# Android PeriodicWorker не работает на Xiaomi?

Tags: android, kotlin, backgroundworker

Дано:
1. Обучающийся нуб в лице меня
2. Телефон Xiaomi Note 8 Pro c 9 android
3. Телефон Samsung Galaxy S6 c 7 android

Надо:
1. Заставить программу выполнять работу в фоне, при полностью закрытом состоянии, в том числе и после перезагрузки. Потом прога должна будет лазать в сеть за данными и проверять их на свежие данные, пока просто notification для теста.

Что делалось:
1. Для проверки работы в фоне вообще, выводятся Notification
2. Перелопачены кучи гайдов с разными подходами, переписывалось всё это не один раз и вечер.
3. Изначально были попытки сделать на IventService - не работало как надо. Посоветовали сделать на PeriodicWorker
4. На финальном этапе уже просто скопипастил код с очердного гайда - не работает.
5. Почесал репу и отрыл старую мобилу, попробовал на ней

Итого:
1. На старой мобиле код работает как от него хочется - прога закрыта, уведомления шлются каждые 15+ минут
2. На новой мобиле - уведомления шлются только когда прога запущена и на экране (телефон в режиме "не отключать экран"). Стоит приложуху просто свернуть, перейдя на главный экран мобилы - уведомления не шлются вообще. При закрытой проге аналогично.

Вопрос:
Вероятно, проблема именно в телефоне (или версии ОС?). Может кто сталкивался с таким? МОжет дело в именно "китайском" производителе? Это можно как-то обойти? Ведь на телефоне есть и другие программы и они в целом в закрытом состоянии порой шлют свои уведомления, значит как-то это реализуется и на таких аппаратах. Может надо вернуться к варианту с IntentService + foreground ?

Главная активи:

```
class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {

    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)

        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)
        setSupportActionBar(toolbar)

        // Тестим workmanager
        val constraints =
            Constraints.Builder()
                .setRequiredNetworkType(NetworkType.CONNECTED)
                .build()

        val workRequest =
            PeriodicWorkRequest
                .Builder(NewsUpdaterWorker::class.java, 15L, TimeUnit.MINUTES)
                .setConstraints(constraints)
                .build()

        WorkManager.getInstance(this).enqueue(workRequest)
    }

}
```

Класс worker

```
private const val TAG = "NewsUpdaterWorker"

class NewsUpdaterWorker(context: Context, params: WorkerParameters) : Worker(context, params) {

    companion object {
        const val NOTIFICATION_ID = "notification_id"
        const val NOTIFICATION_NAME = "new_news"
        const val NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL = "new_news_channel"
    }

    override fun doWork(): Result {
        return try {
            val id = inputData.getLong(NOTIFICATION_ID, 0).toInt()
            sendNotification(id)

            Result.success()
        } catch (error: Throwable) {
            Log.d(TAG, "doWork notification fail")

            Result.failure()
        }
    }

    private fun sendNotification(id: Int) {
        val intent = Intent(applicationContext, MainActivity::class.java)
        intent.flags = FLAG_ACTIVITY_NEW_TASK or FLAG_ACTIVITY_CLEAR_TASK
        intent.putExtra(NOTIFICATION_ID, id)

        val notificationManager =
            applicationContext.getSystemService(NOTIFICATION_SERVICE) as NotificationManager

        val bitmap = applicationContext.vectorToBitmap(R.drawable.ic_schedule_black_24dp)
        val titleNotification = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_new_comic_title)
        val subtitleNotification = applicationContext.getString(R.string.notification_new_comic_subtitle)
        val pendingIntent = getActivity(applicationContext, 0, intent, 0)

        val notification = NotificationCompat.Builder(applicationContext, NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)
            .setLargeIcon(bitmap).setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_schedule_white)
            .setContentTitle(titleNotification).setContentText(subtitleNotification)
            .setDefaults(DEFAULT_ALL).setContentIntent(pendingIntent).setAutoCancel(true)

        notification.priority = PRIORITY_MAX

        if (SDK_INT >= O) {
            notification.setChannelId(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL)


            val ringtoneManager = Uri.parse("android.resource://"
                    + applicationContext.packageName + "/" + R.raw.notifsound)
            val audioAttributes = AudioAttributes.Builder().setUsage(USAGE_NOTIFICATION_RINGTONE)
                .setContentType(CONTENT_TYPE_SONIFICATION).build()

            val channel =
                NotificationChannel(NOTIFICATION_CHANNEL, NOTIFICATION_NAME, IMPORTANCE_HIGH)

            channel.enableLights(true)
            channel.lightColor = RED
            channel.enableVibration(true)
            channel.vibrationPattern = longArrayOf(100, 200, 300, 400, 500, 400, 300, 200, 400)
            channel.setSound(ringtoneManager, audioAttributes)

            notificationManager.createNotificationChannel(channel)
        }
        notificationManager.notify(id, notification.build())

        Log.d(TAG, "Notification send")
    }

    fun Context.vectorToBitmap(drawableId: Int): Bitmap? {
        val drawable = getDrawable(drawableId) ?: return null
        val bitmap = createBitmap(
            drawable.intrinsicWidth, drawable.intrinsicHeight, Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888
        ) ?: return null
        val canvas = Canvas(bitmap)
        drawable.setBounds(0, 0, canvas.width, canvas.height)
        drawable.draw(canvas)
        return bitmap
    }
}
```

Comment: Вроде как дело в ограничениях фоновых процесов на китайцах. Попробуйте явно у юзера на этих девайсах запрашивать разрешение на работу в фоне так: https://stackoverflow.com/a/59539218/3212712. Вроде бы аналогичные запросы делают приложения типа MiFit (приложение к фитнес браслету). Описанные вами уведомления от других приложений скорее всего просто используют механизм FCM для получения данных с сервера и вывода уведомления. На этот способ ограничения фоновых процессов на китайцах не должны распространятся.

Comment: Спасибо, попробую. Вообще, я пробовал вручную у проги ставить в настройках разрешения на автозапуск и т.п. - не помогало. Но там вроде много  всякого перечислено в коде, так что попробую этот вариант.

Comment: на Xiaomi много чего не работает

Comment: @Style-7 А можете расписать подробнее? Чтобы я узнал об этом сейчас, а не после очередной недельной возни с кодом =)